# How can I sort an array of emails by the email provider?

Tags: ruby, arrays, email, sorting

So I dumped all the emails from a DB into a txt file and I`m looking to sort them by email provider, basically anything that comes after the @ sign.

I know I can use regex to validate each email.
However how do I indicate that I want to sort them by anything that comes after the @ sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know I can use regex to validate each email.

Careful! The range of valid e-mail addresses is much wider than most people think. The *only* correct regexes for e-mail validation are on the order of a *page* in length. If you must use a regex, just check for the `@` and one `.`.

> However how do I indicate that I want to sort them by anything that comes after the @ sign

```
email_addresses.sort_by {|addr| addr.split('@').last }
```

Comment: Also, if you still have the e-mail addresses in the DB, you could (and probably should) do this on the DB side.